# Regex to match everything between the first and last occurrence of two distinct characters

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
$str_val = "L(ine 1(
    L(ine 2)
    Line 3
    Line 4)";
$regex = '/\(([^\)]*?)\)/i';
preg_match($regex, $str_val, $matches_arr);
print_r($matches_arr);
```

This code matches everything between the first `(` and the first `)`.

I'm looking for what I would put in `$regex` that would match everything between the first `(` and the last `)`.

I'd appreciate the assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this: -

```
'/\((.*)\)/s'
```

`/s` modifier is used to enable the *dot metacharacter* to match everything including a newline. And, since `.*` is a greedy quantifier, it will match the longest string possible. So, it will match till the last `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\([^\)]*\)
```

The first match is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a greedy search

```
$regex = '/\(.*\)/s';
```

If you really want to have everything *between* `(...)` use this one

```
$regex = '/\((.*)\)/s';
preg_match($regex, $str_val, $matches_arr);
echo $matches_arr[1];
```