# PHP Capture string between characters

Tags: php, regex

What is the best way to capture a string between 2 certain characters in PHP? Looking online some people say to explode it, some suggest using str_ functions, some suggest regex,

```
:>Test!1.221ddba.0_31df0888d4d13e9456a2bdafc93437ff@~127.0.0.1 JOIN UUNN :%#Test
```

I wish to capture the string between the `:` and the `!`, i.e. `>Test`. How can I do this with a regex, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did you try any of the methods you found suggested?

Comment: `or is there a simpler way?` - asking here I guess qualifies as the simpler way.

Comment: Is the string containing only one ":" and one "!", or can they occure multiple times?

Comment: Possibly related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059747/regex-to-match-everything-between-the-first-and-last-occurrence-of-two-distinct

Comment: Also possibly related, although it is Java code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452796/regex-match-everything-between-two

Answer (score 0):

here is the PHP with RegEx. Maybe it helps :)

```
$re = '/(?<=:).*(?=!)/';
$str = ':>Test!1.221ddba.0_31df0888d4d13e9456a2bdafc93437ff@~127.0.0.1 JOIN UUNN :%#Test';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

[Link to Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HjDosU/1)

Comment: This looks Greedy. It will also return wrong results if a string contains un-expected `:` and `!` symbols

Answer (score 0):

After some modifying the answers that i already found I came up with this RegEx

`/(?<=:)[^:!]*(?=!)/miu`

*Regex explanation*:

`(?<=:)` - Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `:` literally
`[^:!]*` - Matches any character except `:` and `!` any number of times.
`(?=!)`  - Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `!` literally.

*A bit basic explanation*

The above regex actually not only grabs every symbol between `:` and `!`, but also ensures, that between these two sybols there are no other occurenses of either `:` or `!`.
 
Actuall, it only maches text that is strictly between `:` and `!`. Everything else is not matched. If there is no `:` followed by a `!` at all then the result will be empty.

This was tested using https://regex101.com/.

Php code generated for the test is

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=:)[^:!]*(?=!)/m';
$str = ':ssuguwuug!jsgejjgjj!yhjyt:feeeeeg!uuuuuuu:uuuuu:uuu!';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the first match result, since it looks like OP only wanted a first match 
var_dump($matches[0]);

?>
```

**EDIT**

I really tried to make it as un-Greedy as I could, but `*` is a Greedy Quantifier